# How to set default editor for bash command line editing

Tags: command-line, bash, text-editors

I was learning bash command line shortcuts and such , when i came across the option to edit the command line in my editor.(Awesome!).

```
$set -o vi 
$echo test1 test2 test3 test4
```

I gave an `ESC` and then pressed `v` and it gave me this error.`-bash: /usr/bin/pico: No such file or directory`.The `EDITOR` variable in my .bashrc is `/usr/bin/vim` which exists and is working normally. But why is this looking for pico in the first place?

Comment: It might be using the editor named in the `VISUAL` variable. Try doing `env | grep 'pico'` that'll find out which variable is referring to `pico`.

Comment: thats it.. will you post this as answer so that i can close this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be using the editor named in the `VISUAL` variable as if set is used as the editor before the `EDITOR` is I think when the program sees that `DISPLAY` is set. Try doing `env | grep 'pico'` that'll find out which variable is referring to `pico`.

There are other variables which programs use to determine which editor to use. `VISUAL` is normally set to a graphical editor or a remote for one. While `EDITOR` is normally set to a console editor. If `VISUAL` is not set the programs instead use `EDITOR`.